# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null when unchecking checkbox

Tags: javascript

There is a function `hideLabels` that should save the current value of selected label and then return it when the checkbox is unchecked back (after it has been checked once). The console says: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null "` but i still can't see where the error is.

```
<script>

 function hideLabels(labelname) {

    var labelInitial=document.getElementById(labelname).innerHTML ;
    if (document.f.test.checked==true) {
        document.getElementById(labelname).innerHTML="";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(labelname).innerHTML=labelInitial;
    } };

function hideComments() {

    hideLabels(label_1) ;
    if (document.f.test.checked==true) {
        document.f.s.style.display="none";
    } else {
        document.f.s.style.display="inline";
    } };

</script>

<FORM name=f >

<label ID="label_1" for="s">Select please!</label>

<SELECT NAME=s>
    <OPTION>First Option</OPTION>
    <OPTION>Second Option</OPTION>
    <OPTION>Third Option</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<BR>

<INPUT name="test" TYPE=checkbox VALUE="test" onChange="hideComments()";>
<INPUT type=button value="Alert" onClick="alert(document.getElementById('label_1').innerHTML)";>

</FORM>
```

Comment: try with "true" instead of true. That might be the problem.

Comment: @AnkitZalani: No. Do not say that: http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/g96PM/

Answer (score 2):

You must wrap parameter with quotes in hideLabels() function, because that parameter is passed as a string.

**UPDATE:**

I hope you're just trying understand basics, because I didn't get why don't you just hide also that label as same as `<select>` element. Or wrap both of them in a div, and than you can just toggle that div visibility. That makes your job easy.

But this is your working way, you should get initial html just when you change, than it will work.

here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2JQQb/) in your way.

And this is How I would do that, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2JQQb/1/)

```
<script>
    function hideComments() {
        var selectDiv = document.getElementById("toggleDiv");
        selectDiv.style.display = (selectDiv.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
    };
</script>
<form name="f">
    <div id="toggleDiv">
        <label ID="label_1" for="s">Select please!</label>
        <select name="s">
            <option>First Option</option>
            <option>Second Option</option>
            <option>Third Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input name="test" type="checkbox" value="test" onchange="hideComments()" ;>
    <input type="button" value="Alert" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('label_1').innerHTML)" ;>
</form>
```

Comment: You are truly my savior, thank you sir!
It worked! But i'va got another problem. 
For some reason value of the label didn't returning back when checkbox is unchecked. Isn't it supposed to be saved in the labelInitial variable?